# Enlarge active window in Kitty Terminal

Tags: terminal, terminator, kitty

Let's assume I have split my Kitty terminal into 3 windows. How can I temporarily maximize the active one so it takes the whole terminal size hiding the non-active windows?

This is done with CTRL + SHIFT + X in Terminator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've found how to achieve this.

First of all, 'stack' layout needs to be enabled. To do so, ensure it appears listed in enabled_layouts:

```
enabled_layouts vertical,stack
```

Then you simply need to add a map/shortcut to load/unload that 'stack' layout:

```
map kitty_mod+x toggle_layout stack
```

In my case, since kitty_mod is equal to CTRL+SHIFT, kitty_mod+x is the exact combination that I wanted.